# Thread Addon doesn't work Blender

Tags: multithreading, blender, freeze

I'd like to run a function in thread and continue to use Blender.

I wrote that script:

```
bpy.ops.wm.console_toggle()
newthreadM = Thread(target = MyFunction())
newthreadM.start()
...
def MyFunction():
    k = ''
    while k != 'm':
        k = input('k :')
```

But Blender is freezing while my function isn't close...
Someone has an idea?

Comment: I got it. There are no "()", after "MyFonction" in target

Comment: If you need help scripting blender go to [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com)